# Send mail form exception : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: ??? ?????? "SendUsing" ???? ?÷?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to make an email form in my website (its a local host for now),
When I run my code, and press on "send", its throwing me this exception :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: ??? ?????? "SendUsing"
>   ???? ?÷?.

what could be the problem?

this is my code :

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>

<script language="c#" runat="server">
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.To = "XXX@gmail.com";

        msg.From = EmailTxt.Text;

        msg.Subject = "Fun With Daniel Email: from" + UsernameTxt.Text;

        msg.Body = MessegeBox.Text;
        msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
        ErrorMessege.Text = "Sending..";


        System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(msg);

        ErrorMessege.Text = "The Email Sent successfully!";



    }

</script>

<td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please insert a Username"
                                    ControlToValidate="UsernameTxt" ForeColor="Red" Display="None" 
                                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Email
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please insert Password"
                                    ControlToValidate="EmailTxt" ForeColor="Red" Display="None" 
                                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Messege
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="MessegeBox" runat="server" Height="100px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You have to write a messege"
                                    ControlToValidate="MessegeBox" ForeColor="Red" Display="None" 
                                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Button2_Click" />

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:Label ID="ErrorMessege" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
```

Comment: Note that System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail is obsolete, it is recommended to go through the System.Net.Mail classes. [See more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx6wtd80.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Web.Mail` requires CDONTs and CDOSYS, so that's the first thing you'll have to look at in this case. See [this](http://www.systemwebmail.com/) site for solutions to common problems.

The fact that there's a whole site dedicated to problems with this namespace should tell you that you're better off using `System.Net.Mail`, which is a native SMTP implementation and does not rely on COM components. Unless you're using .NET 1.x, you should switch to it if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Are you setting the SmtpServer name before you try to send?

It would be set like -

```
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "your mail server name goes here";
```

and should go before `System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(msg);`

Examples for how to use SmtpMail can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.aspx)